# Collecting the value which have the same name in column and row from data frame

Tags: r

```
This is a small example: 
a <- c("a", "b", "f", "c", "e")
b <- c("a", "c", "e", "d", "b")
p <- matrix(1:25, nrow = 5, dimnames = list(a, b))
p <- as.data.frame(p)

#data.frame would be like that
    a    c    e    d    b   
a   1    6    11   16   21     
b   2    7    12   17   22     
f   3    8    13   18   23     
c   4    9    14   19   24
e   5   10    15   20   25
```

The output what I want:

```
  score  
a   1       
b   22                  
c   9    
e   15
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
L <- rownames(p)
output <- NULL
t <- 1
for (i in L) {
  tar_column <- p[i]
  score <- tar_column[t, ]
  tar_score <- matrix(score, nrow = 1, dimnames = list(i, "score"))
  output <- rbind(output, tar_score)
  t <- t+1
}
```

The output I got:

```
score  
a   1       
b   22 

Error in `[.data.frame`(p, i) : undefined columns selected
```

The problem is that column name and rowname are not matched perfectly. I think that the if statement can help to skip the variable when it can't be matched to the column name. Could someone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through each column/rowname (using `sapply`) and use square bracket notation to subset `p` on both that row and column:

```
sapply(c('a','b','c','e'), function(x) p[x,x])
 a  b  c  e 
 1 22  9 15
```

If you don't want to specify the variable names beforehand, you can just use either `colnames` or `rownames`:

```
sapply(colnames(p), function(x) p[x,x])
 a  c  e  d  b 
 1  9 15 NA 22
```

If there isn't a matching rowname, this will return `NA` for that value. If desired, you can drop the NA values by subsetting the result:

```
result <- sapply(colnames(p), function(x) p[x,x])
result[!is.na(result)]
 a  c  e  b 
 1  9 15 22
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
library(tidyverse)

p %>%
  rownames_to_column("row") %>%
  gather(col, score, -row) %>%
  filter(row == col) %>%
  select(-row)
#>   col score
#> 1   a     1
#> 2   c     9
#> 3   e    15
#> 4   b    22
```

First we make the row name into a variable, then we gather from wide to long format, lastly we filter only matching pairs of row and col.